# Use Python to Edit Windows 8 Power Options

Tags: python, windows, windows-8

The Problem: 
Every time I restart my computer my Windows 8 power settings go back to default and puts my computer to sleep after an hour. I don't want my computer to ever go to sleep unless I say so... I have to go in Control Panel > System and Security > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings and manually edit the put the computer to sleep setting to Never.

What I want: 
**A Python script to edit the Power Options in Windows 8.** I will set it to run every time I reboot.

I've searched for a Python module to edit Windows settings but couldn't find what I was looking for. I've played with win32api to control my courser a while back but couldn't find Power Options in its documentation.

---

Julius Caesar's hint about using powercfg command-line options was perfect. 
Here is the simple script I ended up using:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("powercfg -change -standby-timeout-ac 0")
```

The `-standby-timeout-ac` option is set to zero so my computer will Never go to sleep

Comment: Are you trying to place a work order? Do you have a question? Have you tried anything? As is, you appear to want us to write the script _for_ you, which isn't what we're here for.

Comment: @ZAD-Man It does not take a stretch of the imagination to realize I'm asking for guidance that would help me accomplish my goal.
Also I did mention I tried win32api.

Comment: Forgive my indirectness - I was trying to ask you questions that would make it apparent that this question is not suitable for Stack Overflow. Unless you are trying to develop such a script, you should look elsewhere for such recommendations. If you _are_ trying to develop such a script, then you should check out [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Also, I meant to ask if you'd tried writing any code - I was amiss in typing "anything"

Comment: @ZAD-Man Can you educate me in why you think my question is not suitable for StackOverflow? More specifically point out what element in StackOverflow Guidance I did not follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Gladly. :) Look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) instead of the link you provided though. Under the section **Some questions are still off-topic...**, the fourth bullet point describes this situation. It isn't so much that there's a problem with your question, it's that it isn't on-topic for SO.

Comment: @ZAD-Man I did not ask "to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60634/discussion-between-zad-man-and-delicious).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think You should look into [powercfg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powercfg) Windows' command and set whatever You like with python's `subprocess.call`, for example:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("powercfg -change -monitor-timeout-ac 666")
```

I guess it is pretty self-explanatory: change '-ac' to '-dc' for battery setting, value is in minutes and zero stands for infinity, obviously.

Comment: I was looking for a Python module to do this and completely overlooked issuing commands. This worked perfectly - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a solution which heavily involve with win32com.client

It is work on windows 10

```
import win32com.client


class PowerPlan(Computer):

    def __init__(self, mk="//./root/cimv2/power"):
        super(PowerPlan, self).__init__(mk)
        self.power_info = None
        self.power_plan = None

    def get_active_power_plan(self) -> str:

        power_plans = self.wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_powerplan")

        for plan in power_plans:
            if plan.IsActive:
                match = re.search(r'\{(.+?)\}', plan.InstanceID)
                self.power_plan = plan
                return match.group(1)

    def get_power_plan_index(self, guid_id):

        unknown_list = []
        current_power_plan_index = {"AC": {}, "DC": {}}
        power_index = self.wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_powersettingdataindex")
        for power_value in power_index:
            # print(type(power_value))
            # print(dir(power_value))
            match = re.search(guid_id, power_value.InstanceID)
            if match is not None:
                match = re.search(guid_id + r'\}\\(\w{2})\\\{(.+?)\}', power_value.InstanceID)
                power_mode = match.group(1)
                power_tag = match.group(2)
                try:
                    power_word = PowerPlanGUID(power_tag).name
                except Exception as Err:
                    # print("Unknown Tag GUID: " + power_tag)

                    if power_tag not in unknown_list:
                        unknown_list.append(power_tag)
                    continue

                # power_info = {power_word : power_value.settingindexvalue}

                current_power_plan_index[power_mode][power_word] = power_value.settingindexvalue
        self.power_info = current_power_plan_index
        self._json_dump(self.power_info)

    def set_power_plan_value(self, act_plan_guid, power_mode, power_plan_value_guid, value):
        power_index = self.wmi.InstancesOf("Win32_powersettingdataindex")

        for power_setting in power_index:
            match = re.search(act_plan_guid + r'\}\\' + power_mode + r'\\\{' + power_plan_value_guid + r'\}',
                              power_setting.InstanceID)
            # match = re.search(power_plan_value_guid, power_setting.InstanceID)
            if match is not None:
                print(power_setting.InstanceID)
                print(power_setting.settingindexvalue)
                # Properties_
                power_setting.Properties_("SettingIndexValue").Value = value
                # How to make the changed value work
                power_setting.Put_()
                act_method = self.power_plan.Methods_("Activate")
                self.power_plan.ExecMethod_("Activate")

            else:
                pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but there has been a new module published named "powerplan".

```
pip install powerplan
```

Then import the module:

```
import powerplan
```

To get your current power plan scheme use:

```
print(powerplan.get_current_scheme_name())
print(powerplan.get_current_scheme_guid())
```

To change your power plan scheme use:

```
powerplan.change_current_scheme_to_powersaver()
powerplan.change_current_scheme_to_balanced()
powerplan.change_current_scheme_to_high()
```